# Get last bracket name of each html input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms

I need to get the last bracket name from each input of type text.

For example:

```
<input type='text' name='order[bill_address_attributes][firstname]' />
<input type='text' name='order[bill_address_attributes][lastname]' />
<input type='text' name='order[bill_address_attributes][phone]' />
```

Wanted results:

```
firstname
lastname
phone
```

I am able to get the full string value of the attribute `name` by looping through with an `$('input').each()`

Do I need to modify the output string in the `.each()` using regex or is there a better way to do this using jQuery?

Comment: [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) is probably what you want to use.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L7zMc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/B9FNX/)</kbd>

```
var arr =$('input').map(function(){
    return (/\]\[(.+)\]$/g).exec($(this).prop('name'))[1];
}).get();
console.log(arr); //arr is array if you want to convert it to string use arr.join(' ')
```

---

Use RegEXp

```
/\]\[(.+)\]$/g
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without RegExp within your `.each()` loop:

```
$('input:text').each(function(index, value) {
    console.log($(value).attr('name').split('[').pop().replace(']', ''));  
});
```

This will print the value in the last set of brackets for each input to the console.

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jt2Mu/.